# Binding a method that gets a raw buffer pointer using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, numpy, binding, pybind11

I have a class with two overloaded methods called GetBuffer():

```
template < class T>
class Array1D
{
   public:
          
         Array1D()
         {
           Init();
         }
      
         Array1D(const uint32_t size)
         {
           Init();
           SetSize(size);
         }
      
         Array1D(const  Array1D<T> &obj)
         {
            Init();
            *this = obj;
         }
      
         const T& operator[](uint32_t n)const
         {
            S_ASSERT((n < m_nSize));
            return m_pData[n];
         }
      
         T& operator[](uint32_t n)
         {
            S_ASSERT((n < m_nSize));
            return m_pData[n];
         }
    
             
         inline const T* GetBuffer()const
         {
            return m_pData;
         }
      
         inline T* GetBuffer()
         {
            return m_pData;
         }
    
    protected:
          T*m_pData;
          uint32_t m_nSize;      
          uint32_t m_nCapacity;    
          bool    m_bDeleteBuffer; 
};
```

Do you know How I can bind the two overloaded methods GetBuffer() to have an access to this raw buffer in python side ?
I tried this :

```
.def("GetBuffer", (const T* (Array1D<T>::*)() const) &Array1D<T>::GetBuffer, py::return_value_policy::reference_internal)
.def("GetBuffer", (T* (Array1D<T>::*)()) &Array1D<T>::GetBuffer, py::return_value_policy::reference_internal);
```

I still have an error in python side,

```
buff = lut.GetBuffer()
for i in range(lutSize):
     buff[i] = 1000

buff[i] = 1000
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the buffer protocol: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html

Comment: Hi @Artyer, 
Yes of course :

py::class_<Array1D<T>>(m, pyclass_array1D_name.c_str(), py::buffer_protocol())
.def_buffer([](Array1D<T> &m) -> py::buffer_info {  
            return py::buffer_info(m.GetBuffer(), sizeof(T), py::format_descriptor<T>::format(), 1,{m.GetSize()}, {sizeof(T)});
        });

I tried this, but I dont know how we can used it in python side ?

Comment: I resolved the problem
Thank you

Comment: FYI if you resolved, you can self-answer.

Comment: solution :
.def_buffer([](Array1D<T> &m) -> py::buffer_info {  
            return py::buffer_info(m.GetBuffer(), sizeof(T), py::format_descriptor<T>::format(), 1,{m.GetSize()}, {sizeof(T)});
        });

python side :

buff = np.array(lut, copy = False)